# Which java API is best for converting pdf to image

Tags: scala, pdf-reader

I tried with 3 Java APIs for pdf but all 3 did not work properly. 
1. PDFFile
2. PDDocument
3. PDFDocumentReader

If I have a pdf which has a 2 layer in which upper one is bit transparent, so when above 3 APIs converts it into image then only upper layer comes in image with no transparency. But both layer must come.

So suggest me other API to get my requirment fulfill

Code for PDFFile :

```
val raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")
  val channel = raf.getChannel()
  val buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size())
  raf.close()
  val pdffile = new PDFFile(buf)
  val numPgs = pdffile.getNumPages() + 1
  for (i <- 1 until numPgs) {

    val page = pdffile.getPage(i)
    val pwdt = page.getBBox().getWidth().toDouble
    val phgt = page.getBBox().getHeight().toDouble
    val rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pwdt.toInt, phgt.toInt)
    val rsiz = resize(method, size, pwdt, phgt)
    val img = page.getImage(rsiz("width"), rsiz("height"),

      rect, null, true, true)
    result ::= buffer(img)
```

Code for PDDocument :

```
val doc = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(file));
val pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages()
for (i <- 0 until pages.size()) {
      val page = pages.get(i)
      val before = page.asInstanceOf[PDPage].convertToImage()
}
```

Code for PDFDocumentReader :

```
val inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
        val document = new PDFDocumentReader(inputStream)
        val numPgs = document.getNumberOfPages

        for (i <- 0 until numPgs) {
          val pageDetail = new PageDetail("", "", i, "")
          val resourceDetails = document.getPageAsImage(pageDetail)
          val image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(resourceDetails.getBytes()))
          result ::= image
}
```

Comment: It's a difficult problem, and nothing does a perfect job. We use this product: http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdfl/ - not pure Java, does does come with a Java API.

Comment: @Rishi I was put on a project like this. I can tell you there are no good solutions. None of them can perfectly render a page or handle all image types. Some have trouble with fonts others with image types, etc. You're going to have to convince management to take the lesser of evils.